# Distance calculation between the descriptors in knnMatch, FlannBasedMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv

In `knnMatch` method , in we calculate the distance to this n-th nearest neighbour. I want to know which distance are they calculating. Whether its Euclidean distance or what?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is question is kind of repost. You should better search it before asking. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897475/which-distance-function-does-flannbasedmatcher-use-and-how-to-change-it) is the answer for your question. Think/research twice before asking a question ;)

And also reading [this](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/09muja.pdf) paper will also help you.

Comment: Actually i searched alot, but couldnt find what i want